# alias_method_chain on an HABTM attribute's setter isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, overriding, has-and-belongs-to-many, setter, alias-method-chain

So I have a HABTM for both Posts and Topics.  A Post HABTM Topics, and a Topic HABTM Posts.  What I need to do is call some method in conjunction with calling `post.topics=()`

This is what I've tried doing in Post.rb:

```
def topics_with_extra_stuff=(topics)
  topics_without_extra_stuff=(topics)
  extra_stuff()
end
alias_method_chain :topics=, :extra_stuff
```

However, this now breaks `post.topics=()`

I won't get an error or anything, but `topics()` will still be the old value after changing it with `topics=()`

If I raise an error in `topics_with_extra_stuff=`, the trace will say that there was an error in `topics=`, so I know it's getting in there.  I also know that `extra_stuff()` was called.

Here's an example of the output:

```
>> p = Post.last
=> #<Post id:1 ....>
>> p.topics
=> [#<Topic id:1 ....>, #<Topic id:2 ....>]
>> p.topics = [ p.topics.first ]
=> [#<Topic id:1 ....>]
>> p.topics
=> [#<Topic id:1 ....>, #<Topic id:2 ....>]
```

It shouldn't still have 2 Topics, just 1.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using the association callback `:before_add` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem (Rails 2.3.11), but adding a `before_add` callback was not an option for me so I kept looking. Finally I managed to make it work using this alternative way of aliasing:

```
old_workflows_setter = self.instance_method(:workflows=)

define_method :workflows= do |value|
  # my code
  old_workflows_setter.bind(self).call(value)
end
```

Comment: As of rails 3.2 i don't think you'll need to do that - association accessors are created in a module include into your class so you should be able to just redefine and call super()